# SQLite: group_concat only seems to pull first row?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, group-concat

I have a base query which functions as desired, and tells me which people have how many items for thing 'a':

`SELECT Person || '  ' || COUNT(ResponsibleThing) FROM table WHERE thing='a' GROUP BY Person;`

```
Person || ' ' || COUNT(ResponsibleThing)
-----------------------------------------------
Joe     340
Chris   34
Dave    612
Fred    272
```

What I really want is to collapse this result set into a CSV so that I can pivot on another column, with a result set that looks something like:

```
thing Person || '   ' || COUNT(ResponsibleThing)
----- -----------------------------------------
a     Joe     340,Chris     34,Dave     612,Fred    272
b     Chris     100, Frank     34
```

It seemed like `group_concat` would be the way to go, but strangely, I'm only getting back the first entry when I try to adapt the above query:
`SELECT group_concat((SELECT Person || '  ' || COUNT(ResponsibleThing) FROM table WHERE thing='a' GROUP BY Person));`

```
group_concat((SELECT Person || '  ' || COUNT(ResponsibleThing) FROM table WHERE thing='a' GROUP BY Person))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Joe     340
```

Any ideas on how to get the full result set to be concatenated?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation: first by person (that's your existing query), then overall:

```
select group_concat(res) res
from (
    select person || ' ' || count(*) res
    from mytable
    where thing = 'a'
    group by person
) t
```